# Encryption using libsodium and need to generate public and private keys using crypto_box_keypair()

Tags: iphone, xcode, encryption, libsodium

Need some help. I am working on encryption, where I need to implement `crypto_box_keypair()` or decode a hex string to a byte array so that you have to get a public and private keys. I also need to call `crypto_box(m,n,pk,sk)` for encryption.

I have never worked on encryption, I struck with how to implement. If you have any sample code, could you please send. which will be very help full. I just need to encrypt and decrypt string in ios.

Thanks in advnce.

Comment: Interestingly, very recently there have been three questions about "lib sodium" and "crypto_box". What course or common project is this from?

Comment: Hi Zaph, I found this as secure encryption and thought to implement on encrypting and decrypting simple string in iOS. If you can please help .

Comment: For general encryption the usual method is to use Symmetric Key encryption with the AES algorithm. Public Key encryption is generally used to encrypt small amounts of data, usually symmetric keys. But I am still wondering why suddenly there are three questions involving "lib sodium" and "crypto_box"